# Jekyll and Strapi: Liquid Exception: Please make sure Strapi Server is correctly running

Tags: mongodb, jekyll, static-site, strapi, headless-cms

I am currently trying to follow this tutorial (https://blog.strapi.io/building-a-static-website-using-jekyll-and-strapi/) and everything was working fine until the "Posts List" step. Once I added the _layouts/home.html file and restarted the jekyll server (bundle exec jekyll serve), I ended up with an error message:

> Liquid Exception: The Strapi server sent a error with the following status: 404. Please make sure it is correctly running. in /_layouts/home.html
> jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  The Strapi server sent a error with the following status: 404. Please make sure it is correctly running.

Thing is, the strapi server IS RUNNING... I have access to the the strapi admin backend and I can access and view the Posts json object by visiting: http://localhost:1337/posts.

I'm not actually too sure what is going on and how I can fix this. Documentation doesn't help nor can I seem to find anything on this issue in google or stack overflow.

Anyone else got this issue?

Here is the content of home.html:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">
    <h1 class="page-heading">Posts</h1>
    {%- if strapi.collections.posts.size > 0 -%}
    <ul class="post-list">
        {%- for post in strapi.collections.posts -%}
        <li>
            <span class="post-meta">{{ post.createdAt | date_to_string }} by {{ post.author.username }}</span>
            <h3>
                <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
                    {{ post.title }}
                </a>
            </h3>
            <!-- Display an excerpt of the article -->
            <p>{{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 10 }}</p>
        </li>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
</div>
```

EDIT: added Endpoint Config

```
strapi:  
# Your API endpoint (optional, default to http://localhost:1337)
  endpoint: http://localhost:1337
  # Collections, key is used to access in the strapi.collections
  # template variable
  collections:
    # Example for a "posts" collection
    posts:
    # Collection name (optional). Used to construct the url requested. Example: type `foo` would generate the following url `http://localhost:1337/foo`.
      type: post
      # Permalink used to generate the output files (eg. /posts/:id).
      permalink: /posts/:slug/
```

Comment: could you post your config file please? specifically where you have included information about your strapi endpoint etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working... I ended up updating jekyll-strapi to lastest version 0.1.2, and jekyll to version 3.8.5.

I already had the gem jekyll-strapi installed, so to update it, I did in a Terminal:

```
gem install jekyll-strapi
```

This ensure that you have the newest latest version with bug fixes.

Next, your gemfile should be configured like this:

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"
[...]
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
  gem 'jekyll-strapi', github: 'strapi/jekyll-strapi'
end
```

The "github: 'strapi/jekyll-strapi'" parameter will make sure you have the latest fix for the infamous bug: "Liquid Exception: Can't convert Integer into String"

One more thing, in blog/_config.yml, instead of "type: post"

```
strapi:
  collections:
    posts:
      type: post
```

**YOU NEED TO make 'post' plural**. So, you will end up with:

```
strapi:
  collections:
    posts:
      type: posts
```

If you don't you will end up with this error: "Liquid Exception: The Strapi server sent a error with the following status: 404. Please make sure it is correctly running. in /_layouts/home.html"

I hope it helps someone else struggling with this tutorial. With gems and frameworks moving and updating fast, some online tutorial become dated and out of synch with the latest builds.